# how can i store the JsonExtractor return in an array after each http request in Jmeter?

Tags: javascript, java, jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

I have a JsonExtractor, which takes the value returned in the "requestprotocolId", I use it in the next Thread Group because this value is passed in the next API request, but when I make 50 requests for example, it will return 50 "requestProtocolId"  but they they will not return all at once, it will be one per request, so I want the value returned in this field to be stored in an array at each request, and when I finish the Thread Group and move to the next one I can use all these "requestProtocolId" in the next request , one at a time. Would it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. The next request doesn't have to necessary be in the "next Thread Group", it can be in the same Thread Group, this way you won't have to convert [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) (which are [thread-local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage)) into JMeter Properties or use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)
2. If you want to collect 50 "requestprotocolId"s from 50 separate requests into some form of array - it can be done using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor), take a look at the following materials:

   - [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
   - [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: vars.get("${requestProtocolId}");
def protocolArray = [] as String[10]
for (i=0; i <= protocolArray.length; i++){
protocolArray[i]= "${requestProtocolId}";
}

ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (ArrayList) values: [[10]]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), any(groovy.lang.Closure), tap(groovy.lang.Closure), take(int)
*************

accesses the "for" loop but gives this error.